# clean url onClick problem

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a RewriteRule in my site and it's working fine but 1 part of my javascript doesn't work.

```
<a href="#" onClick="check('1')">Click</a>

<div id="1" style="padding: 5px; display: none;">
    MyText
</div>
```

normaly i had www.mysite.com?page=home and when i click it work like www.mysite.com?page=home#
but with the RewriteRule i got www.mysite.com/home/ but my onClick doesn't work anymore.

How can i fix this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return false...

```
<a href="#" onclick="check('1'); return false;">Click</a>
```